# Adding reference partitioning to oracle table

Tags: oracle, partitioning

on the 12c version of oracle I have created **T_App** table like this:

```
create table T_APP
(
    C_ID          NUMBER(34, 0)      not null,
    C_ACTIVE      number(1, 0)       not null,
    C_APPID       varchar2(255 char) not null,
    C_CONTACTTYPE varchar2(255 char) not null,
    primary key (C_ID)
)
    partition by list(C_CONTACTTYPE)
(
    partition p1 values ('default')
);
```

and **T_APPUSER** table like this:

```
create table T_APPUSER
(
    C_ID          NUMBER(34, 0) primary key,
    C_ACTIVE      number(1, 0)  not null,
    C_DEVICETOKEN varchar2(255 char),
    C_SSOID       varchar2(255 char),
    F_APP     NUMBER(34, 0) not null,
    constraint FK_APP
        foreign key (F_APP)
            references T_APP
)
            PARTITION BY REFERENCE (FK_APP);
```

but when I run the query of creating T_APPUSER I get ERROR!
is there anyThing wrong with my query for creating the T_APPUSER table?

Comment: For reference partitioning, you need to partition T_APP first. Which column do you want to partition on in T_APP?

Comment: I have partitioned T_APP by list on C_CONTACTTYPE column

Comment: then I want to run this query:                                                                                
 create table T_APPUSER
(
    C_ID          NUMBER(34, 0) primary key,
    C_ACTIVE      number(1, 0)  not null,
    C_DEVICETOKEN varchar2(255 char),
    C_SSOID       varchar2(255 char),
    F_FCM_APP     NUMBER(34, 0) not null,
    constraint FK_APP
        foreign key (F_APP)
            references T_APP
)
            PARTITION BY REFERENCE (FK_FCMAPP);

Comment: but I got  [42000][906] ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis EROR

Comment: OK. Can you please edit your question and add the `PARTITION` you have used to T_APP, so that it becomes clear to other users that see your question?

Comment: Hmm, works for me, I don't get any error

Comment: @wolφi but i get  ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis :|||

Comment: I've just copied the CREATE statement from your question, and it works fine for me. What tool do you use to run the statement? SQL Developer?

Comment: I use the dataBase console of IntelliJ IDE

Comment: I am sure that the syntax in your question is ok. Open a new console and copy from stackoverflow to IntelliJ. I usually use `references`  with the target column, like 'references T_APP(C_ID)`. And you could try to put the foreign key on one line, and the `PARTITION` a space after the last ')'. If that doesn't help, make a copy of the create t_appuser statement and remove the other columns, like `create table T_APPUSER (F_APP NUMBER(34, 0) not null);`. If that works, add slowly complexity back until you find the typo...